# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Is there any documentation on how to use the Razor view engine using ASP.NET MVC 3?

Or any other resources?

I am trying to find it in Google and MSDN with no luck so far.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would think that there will be no official documentation on MSDN as yet due to the status of the Razor and MVC3. However check

1. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/27/introducing-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx
2. [Introducing “Razor” – a new view engine for ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx)
3. [ASP.NET MVC 3: New @model keyword in Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx)
4. [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx)
5. [ASP.NET MVC 3: Server-Side Comments with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/12/asp-net-mvc-3-server-side-comments-with-razor.aspx)
6. [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and  syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)
7. [ASP.NET MVC 3: Implicit and Explicit code nuggets with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/16/asp-net-mvc-3-implicit-and-explicit-code-nuggets-with-razor.aspx)
8. [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)
9. [Razor Syntax Quick Reference - Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)
10. [Introduction to ASP.NET Web Programming Using the Razor Syntax](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)
11. [ASP.NET MVC 3 and the @helper syntax within Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)
12. [[MSDN Labs] ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VS2010TrainingCourse_ASPNETMVC3Razor)

[Haacked](http://haacked.com/tags/razor/default.aspx) also has a post as well, and provides link to other resources including ,[Brad Wilson](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/), Scott Gu and others.

**New:** http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes

Answer (score 5):

Until documentation is out specific to MVC3, you might want to start with the Razor docs available for the Web Matrix Beta 3 release.  There is good information available on the syntax and structure of Razor.

Online:  [introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)

PDF: [ASPNETWebPagesWithRazorSyntax-Book-Beta3.pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/6/D/D6DFC36D-604F-448A-A189-15EC874ABAAF/ASPNETWebPagesWithRazorSyntax-Book-Beta3.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

pls try the link :

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=41&srcfamilyid=300314da-dedd-4540-a236-a0de0a5a534d&srcdisplaylang=en&u=http%3a%2f%2fdownload.microsoft.com%2fdownload%2fC%2f9%2f2%2fC9288B42-5C25-474D-A51A-1BA3749C4DBF%2fASPNETWebPagesWithRazorSyntax-Book.pdf

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15979

Comment: Some explanation of what's on the other end of these links would be helpful. Also, use the formatting to change the long url to some meaningful link text.